# Send order to thermal printer for printing receip

Tags: php, thermal-printer

I am using a php, Jquery, html5 so as to construct a POS. I am stuck to the point where i need to send the order to the thermal printer for printing the receipt. Before sending the command i need to define the receipt template including the relevant data from the order. Does anybody knows the standard sizes of such a receipt? + any PHP class used to connect to the thermal printer for printing the receipt?

Thank you very much

Comment: How is the printer connected to the server running the PHP? Directly via cable (USB, LPT) or via network?

Comment: dupl... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25973046/printing-to-pos-printer-from-php

Comment: Via network.. it is a web based POS accessible through a browser