# Printer Connection error on escpos-php

Tags: php, printing, escpos

From This link([Printing to POS printer from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25973046/printing-to-pos-printer-from-php)) i started I have use php sample code. my question is my printer is set to default then why i have to connect to printer. anyway i am getting error on connecting printer.
as my printer name is in fig1 and to access printer i have to type \Sah-it\ARP-808K in run as shown in fig2.
i have tried:

1.

```
$connector = new FilePrintConnector("\\Sah-it\ARP-808K");
$printer = new Printer($connector);
```

2.

```
$profile = CapabilityProfile::load("simple");
$connector = new WindowsPrintConnector("smb://Sah-it/ARP-808Kr");
$printer = new Printer($connector, $profile);
```

3.

```
$connector = new NetworkPrintConnector("\\Sah-it\ARP-808K");
$printer = new Printer($connector);
```

all gives me connection error. Kindly help me to connect printer. Thanks

Fig1:

[image]

Fig2:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've personally not used [ESC/POS Print Driver for PHP](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php) library but the documentation does state the use in a fairly detailed way. Judging by your images, you have a printer shared from a server called `\\Sah-it\ARP-808K`. To connect (guessing the printer is an Epson), it's advised you do the following:

```
    use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector;
    use Mike42\Escpos\CapabilityProfile;
    $profile = CapabilityProfile::load("simple");
    $connector = new WindowsPrintConnector("smb://Sah-it/ARP-808K");
    $printer = new Printer($connector, $profile);
```

***Note:  Suitable for Epson TM-series printers so check [documentation](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php) to ensure your printer is supported***

If your having issues with the above via hostname, then check your PHP servers DNS configuration as it may not be able to resolve `Sah-it`. In this instance I would suggest trying to connect via IP to the printer (if networked) or to your print-server's IP using the following:

```
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\NetworkPrintConnector;
use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;
$connector = new NetworkPrintConnector("10.x.x.x", 9100); //Printer/Server IP
$printer = new Printer($connector);
try {
    // ... Print stuff
} finally {
    $printer -> close();
}
```

if you have further issues then add your printer make and model, confirm your Webserver can resolve `\\Sah-it` and add any relevant errors which may help.

Comment: Geting these Errors:
1.
Warning: copy(\\Sah-it\ARP-808K): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\wamp\www\p\vendor\mike42\escpos-php\src\Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector.php on line 372
2.
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Failed to copy file to printer' in C:\wamp\www\p\vendor\mike42\escpos-php\src\Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector.php on line 291
3.
Exception: Failed to copy file to printer in C:\wamp\www\p\vendor\mike42\escpos-php\src\Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector.php on line 291

Comment: Check this Issue on Github: https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php/issues/67

Comment: It goes through debugging the printer connection. Also try via IP and Port as it seems this is definitely a connection issue from your WAMP server to Printer.

Comment: Someone also mentioned changing the permissions on the printer to `Full Control` for the NETWORK account.

Comment: Thanks I have Tried this smb://bob:secret@computer/workgroup/printer and its working

Comment: No worries and glad it's sorted.

Comment: there? i am facing problem as i am using WindowsPrintConnector on live server i am geting error no printer found: 
"Failed to print. Command "net use "\\Sah-it\ARP-808K" "/user:USMAN" "*****"" failed with exit code 2: System error 53 has occurred. The network path was not found."
as i am running same pc its working locally perfect

Comment: Can you  ping `sah-it` from your server using command prompt? Does nslookup resolve to the correct IP address from your server using command prompt? Have you tried using up address direct?

Comment: Its server of godady how can I ping?

Comment: If your server is hosted In Datacenter and your printer is only accessible on your LAN then how did you expect for it to be able to communicate using just Sah-it? Your going to need to either make this printer accessible externally (huge security risks) or VPN into your LAN from your Dedicated Server.