# Send data to receipt printer through a PHP web page

Tags: php, printing, epson

I have a web page that is hosted in a linux server. From this page a client can make an order. When the order is confirmed i want to send the data of the order to the local company that has an Epson thermal receipt printer ethernet connected .
I saw a few things like [qz](https://github.com/qzind/tray)
but i don't know where to start from.
For example let's say that the company has an external IP 10.10.10.10 and the thermal printer has an internal IP 192.168.1.200
Also let's say that i open port 8080 on router so that every request on 10.10.10.10:8080 is sent to the printer.
Found other solutions for local networks but none for accessing the local POS printer from a web server.
I also saw a few things here [escpos-php](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php/blob/b79a8050cdb0a0314e7d87253b62ca39eb4a4be6/doc/FAQ.md#can-i-print-from-my-server-on-the-internet) but i need some help on how and where to start from

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing to POS printer from PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25973046/printing-to-pos-printer-from-php)

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix edit my question to clarify what i look for

Answer (score 0):

I found this one [Printnode](https://printnode.com/) Seems pretty good, easy and cheap. It has an API and supports PHP

Answer (score 0):

first you sharing print name in php code, go your system printer properties option and click tab (sharing) click checkbox "share this printer" that get name your sharing use it. And you should use WindowsPrintConnector('printer sharing name')